# How to convert a file into File Entity

Tags: 8, entities, files

I need to use [file_copy](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21file.module/function/file_copy/8.6.x) in a custom module in D8.

The function `file_copy` requires the first parameter to be a `File Entity`. Here is what I have tried but it doesn't work and returns an error:

**TypeError: Argument 1 passed to file_copy() must be an instance of Drupal\file\FileInterface, instance of stdClass given**.

```
$file_path = drupal_realpath("public://Testttt58.png");
$file = (object) array(
            'uid' => 1,
            'uri' => $file_path,
            'filemime' => mime_content_type($file_path),
            'display' => 1,
            'filename' => "Testttt58.png"
);
$fileUpload = file_copy($file, "public://TestFolder", FILE_EXISTS_RENAME);
```

Here is the output of `kint($file);`

[image]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use something like this:

```
use Drupal\file\Entity\File;
$file = File::create([
  'uri' => $file_path,
  'filemime' => mime_content_type($file_path),
  'filename' => "Testttt58.png",
]);
$fileUpload = file_copy($file, "public://TestFolder", FILE_EXISTS_RENAME);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`file_save_data`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21file.module/function/file_save_data/8.8.x) to save a file and create the managed file object.

e.g:

```
$filepath = 'public://Testttt58.png';
// Save the file, using the file contents in $data
$file = file_save_data($data, $filepath, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE)
```